# R stop - condition object

Tags: r

What is a condition object in R? I am reading `help(stop)` and it says:

> ... zero or more objects which can be coerced to character (and which are pasted together with no separator) or a single condition object.

At first I thought this will be some expression returning logical value, but apparently this is not the case as the following code runs without error when it should produce a warning:

```
> stop(1 > 0, 'Test')
Error: TRUETest
```

> If a condition object is supplied it should be the only argument, and further arguments will be ignored, with a warning.

What is a condition object and what is the use case for it in R?

Answer (score 1):

See `help(conditions)` for info. There's examples and everything.